# how to make spread syntax work with "export const pipes = _pipes" in NgModule's declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, spread-syntax, ng-modules

[StackBlitz for this problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lxxjhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

I want to create some constant pipes and import them all together in `app.module.ts`.

It works when I use syntax like `export const pipes = [MinValue, MaxValue]`, but does not work when I use `export const pipes = _pipes`, it says that `No pipe found with name 'MIN_VALUE'`.

The problem is that I want to put the logic of the same constant together, if I use the first approach, when there are a lot of constants in the file, I need to jump here and there when adding or removing constants. So, is it possible to make the second approach work?

`constant.ts`:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

const _pipes = [];

@Pipe({ name: 'MIN_VALUE' })
export class MinValue implements PipeTransform {
  transform = (v?: any) => 1;
}
_pipes.push(MinValue);

@Pipe({ name: 'MAX_VALUE' })
export class MaxValue implements PipeTransform {
  transform = (v?: any) => 10;
}
_pipes.push(MaxValue);

export const pipes = _pipes; // <- this does not work
// export const pipes = [MinValue, MaxValue]; // <- this works
```

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { pipes } from './constant';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...pipes], // <- spread syntax here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: @Makusium it demonstrates the errors OP is having currently.

Comment: @Makusium it's the problem I'm referring to

Comment: OP, @Eldar thanks.